# Delete file on server

Tags: c#, filesystems, delete-file, mappath

I have a file path in the format `file://SERVERNAME/FOLDER$/FOLDER/image.jpg`. I call `System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(file://SERVERNAME/FOLDER$/FOLDER/image.jpg))` to delete the file, but i get the error `file:/SERVERNAME/FOLDER$/FOLDER/image.jpg' is not a valid virtual path.` I notice that a '/' is missing and I do not know why. How will I delete such file?

I have tried converting my file path to `file:////SERVERNAME//FOLDER$//FOLDER//image.jpg` but this did not help. Same thing happens. If I omit the `Server.MapPath`, I get an error saying URI is not supported.

How to do this please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are doing `System.IO.File.Delete` I assume you have the permission to delete the file; so you can:

```
var uri = new Uri("file://SERVERNAME/FOLDER$/FOLDER/image.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
System.IO.File.Delete(uri.LocalPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

> \\SERVERNAME\FOLDER$\FOLDER\image.jpg

make sure the user account running the application has access to remote machine

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have enough permissions to access that file, you need to convert the given path to `\\SERVERNAME\FOLDER$\FOLDER\image.jpg`